# How to I know hard disk members of any Virtual Disk LSI RAID with MEgaRaid

Tags: raid, shell, megacli

i get a machine with a LSI MEgarad card.
I know what Virtual Diska has:

```
Adapter: 0
Product Name: LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i
Memory: 512MB
BBU: Absent
Serial No: SV11807006
==============================================================================
Number of DISK GROUPS: 3
```

But i don't know wat disk are on each Virtual disk (0,1,2) and what disk are HotSpare...

```
 MegaCli -LDInfo -Lall -aAll


 Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
 Virtual Disk: 0 (Target Id: 0)
 Name:
 RAID Level: Primary-5, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
 Size:16.371 TB
 State: Optimal
 Stripe Size: 64 KB
 Number Of Drives per span:3
 Span Depth:3
 ....
 Check Consistency        : Completed 46%, Taken 254 min.

 Virtual Disk: 1 (Target Id: 1)
 Name:
 RAID Level: Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
 Size:2.728 TB
 State: Optimal
 Stripe Size: 64 KB
 Number Of Drives:1
 Span Depth:1

 Virtual Disk: 2 (Target Id: 2)
 Name:
 RAID Level: Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
 Size:2.728 TB
 Stripe Size: 64 KB
 Number Of Drives:1
 Span Depth:1
```

I looking for a command of MegaCli for know map of Disk of every Virtual Disk

Thanks

Comment: megactl is much easier to use and will give you the information you are looking for without parsing MegaCli's convoluted help output - http://sourceforge.net/projects/megactl/

Comment: ./Megacli -help would fetch you all the options with which you can check the controller details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command will list each virtual drive followed by each physical disk which is a member of that virtual drive.

```
MegaCli64 -LdPdInfo -aAll
```

Answer (score 2):

In Linux: Find all logical drives, reporting their physical disks by Enclosure Device ID/Slot Number:

```
# megacli -LdPdInfo -aAll | egrep "^Adapter|^Number of Virtual|^Virtual Drive:|^Name|^Enclosure Device ID:|^Slot Number:"
```

...Compare to ALL drives, showing their Adapter, Enclosure Device ID, and Slot Number:

```
# megacli -PDList -aALL | egrep 'Adapter|Enclosure Device ID:|Slot'
```